# Random sort based on parameter

Tags: algorithm, math, sorting

I would like to create a sorting function based on user input.

Assume that you have:

- Ordered integer list or vector, **X**,  from 1 to 10.
- Function F
- Parameter t
- Output list **Y**

What I would to do 'is a consistent function between

`F(X, t) = Y`

I mean for same t, it must provide same Y.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Seed your random generator with *t* and shuffle the list.

Answer (score 0):

I guarantee there is a better answer than this, and I admit I don't quite understand @GeorgScholly's answer, but maybe the function you're looking for is a polynomial, which can be obtained via interpolation.

For example, say your vector **X** has two integers, **x<sub>0</sub>**, **x<sub>1</sub>**, and so your output vector **Y** must have two integers, **y<sub>0</sub>**, **y<sub>1</sub>**. There is a line **y=ax+b** that fits any two points **(x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>)** and **(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>)**.

In general, **n** points, **(x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>) ... (x<sub>n-1</sub>, y<sub>n-1</sub>)**, can always be *perfectly fit* by a polynomial of degree **n-1**, *i.e.* a function, **y = a<sub>n-1</sub>x<sup>n-1</sup> + a<sub>n-2</sub>x<sup>n-2</sup> + ... + a<sub>2</sub>x<sup>2</sup> + a<sub>1</sub>x + a<sub>0</sub>**.

These coefficients, **a<sub>n-1</sub> ... a<sub>0</sub>**, can be found by many methods of "polynomial interpolation." Effectively, the coefficients in vector form would define your function, **F(x)**.

Finally, to incorporate a parameter **t**, you might simply add am "unnecessary" term, *i.e.* match two points with a parabola (not a line), match three points with a cubic (not a parabola), etc., in order to have an additional **a<sub>n</sub>** to use as a fixed point, **t**.

I'll be very surprised if there isn't a much simpler way (if @GoergScholly's answer isn't already one).